# Yamlbeans parsing exception Expected data for a com.beans.Score field but found: scalar

Tags: yaml

Need some help with Yamlbeans (v1.06), I am trying to parse the following message:

{MessageId: 123, ReceiptHandle: receiptHandle, MD5OfBody: 34536563, Body: !com.beans.Score
created_at: '"2010-03-29 "'
custom_1: 20
custom_3: S1040PERbfdi10103216
exit_code: 1
first_activity_at: '"2010-03-29 "'
last_activity_at: '"2010-03-29 "'
prod_id: 0
score: '"0.549305"'
, Attributes: {}, }

Below is the snippet of code i use to parse:
    YamlReader reader = new YamlReader(msg);
    Object object = reader.read();

Error:
com.esotericsoftware.yamlbeans.YamlReader$YamlReaderException: Line 17, column 1: Expected data for a com.beans.Score field but found: scalar
    at com.esotericsoftware.yamlbeans.YamlReader.readValueInternal(YamlReader.java:357)
    at com.esotericsoftware.yamlbeans.YamlReader.readValue(YamlReader.java:156)
    at com.esotericsoftware.yamlbeans.YamlReader.readValueInternal(YamlReader.java:289)
    at com.esotericsoftware.yamlbeans.YamlReader.readValue(YamlReader.java:156)
    at com.esotericsoftware.yamlbeans.YamlReader.read(YamlReader.java:106)
    at com.esotericsoftware.yamlbeans.YamlReader.read(YamlReader.java:91)
    at com.esotericsoftware.yamlbeans.YamlReader.read(YamlReader.java:83)

Can anybody please help with this?

Answer (score 0):

1) make sure your Score fields (created_at, custom_1, etc) are indented from the Score declaration, eg:

```
Body: 
    !com.beans.Score
        created_at: '"2010-03-29 "'
        custom_1: 20
```

2) you generally don't need quotes for scalar values like 2010-03-29